# Rotating a PDF in Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, pdf

I have a PDF on Google Docs, but the image is sideways. I would like to rotate the document so it can be read, but I don't want to install any PDF editing software.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Docs doesn't support it, but there is [Rotate PDF](http://rotatepdf.net/) which is a free online service.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution which doesn't require any other software or services outside of Google Drive:

1. Open PDF in the Google Drive viewer
2. Click on the Print button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>)
3. Click on the Cancel button (or <kbd>Esc</kbd>)
4. Right click on the PDF and choose Rotate Clockwise or Rotate Counterclockwise

Referenced from [here](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/drive/RrIA09Lbz2E/BLaV7BWrRE4J).

#### Before Rotation

[image: Before Rotation]

#### After Rotation

[image: After Rotation]

Comment: Clever. This might not be the best answer for the OP, who has edit access to the file, but it answers _my_ question quite nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Does not save the document back to drive as rotated.

Comment: This is completely dependent on what browser you use and what PDF viewer is configured in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

There's a free online PDF editor called [PDFescape](http://www.pdfescape.com/) that will let you upload, rotate, and save PDFs.

Comment: Does not work with Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

[Sejda PDF](https://www.sejda.com) has a [Rotate PDF](https://www.sejda.com/rotate-pdf-pages) tool and it integrates with Google Drive.

1. Add the [Sejda PDF app](https://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2F%23%3Faction%3Dapps%26appId%3Djahgelfminhmpjfjoojmdnjegblkpnjp) to your Google Drive
2. In GDrive right click a document > Open with Sejda PDF
3. Rotate the PDF pages
4. Save back to your Google Drive

Comment: Sejda PDF app is a kind of link to an online PDF editor. It would be nicer to have a tool integrated to Google Drive.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Adobe Reader X and rotate it.

Comment: The OP explicitly states that installing other software is not a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do it is to download the file and open it into a dedicated PDF read like Adobe Read or Foxit.

Comment: The OP specifically said he did _not_ want to install PDF software.