# How can I do some touch-ups on an uploaded/online PDF?

Tags: webapp-rec, pdf

I have been given a PDF form with some mistakes here and there. Also there is some misalignment in some of the form boxes. Offline, I would just use the Advanced Editing option from Adobe Acrobat Professional but I do not have this installed on all machines. This would be the case if I am traveling.

I looked at the advice from [Best way to rotate a PDF](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/best-way-to-rotate-a-pdf) but the limitations are

- You cannot edit the text, you can whiteout and use a basic text
- Cannot upload fonts to use to match the text already there
- File sizes must be less than 2MB/ 50 pages

How can I step over (some of) these limitations without having to install some software?

Answer (score 1):

I use Buzzword (https://acrobat.com/) itself to update the online PDF content.
The best in town, as its by the creator itself.

Comment: @Jwalant your signature is already "signed" with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page.

Comment: This looks good as long as I have not created the PDF with Buzzword yet but with the phrasing of my question I guess you went with the online PDF option. Not sure its the same, are you able to edit a PDF that you created from Adobe Reader,Microsoft Word ..etc and edit in Buzzword?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.pdfescape.com/.  That site should allow you to do whatever you want.

If that doesn't suite your needs checkout http://www.nitropdf.com/free/hammer/index.htm.

Comment: Thanks, PDFEscape is the app in question the limitations are about see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/best-way-to-rotate-a-pdf as I posted above. Nitro PDF just seems to rearrange the page ordering. Nitro PDF Professional Software seems to do edits but that defeats the purpose , I might as well download Adobe Professional

Answer (score 0):

The [ActivePDF Toolkit](http://www.activepdf.com/products/serverproducts/toolkit/index.cfm) contains a terrific API for modifying PDF files programmatically. It's primarily a .Net ToolKit but it's capable of doing it all behind the scenes.

Comment: Looks really good. Does not seem to touch any objects on the page. Closest I am seeing is page numbering and adding headers can you confirm ?

Answer (score -1):

i would look at a tool such as Cute PDF which allows you to edit as needed.

Comment: I looked at the [homepage](http://www.cutepdf.com/), is there a web application version?  I don't see one.

Comment: This doesn't answer the portion of the question "without having to install some software"